# How to make a CSS scroll follow div stop follow at a position

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/JjuQu/30/)

I want the scrolling div stop following when left div ends at height=400px.

Is there any solution using CSS. Or I need to add other html elements?

If have to use JavaScript, how to do it?

Comment: not quite sure what you meant by "stop following", could you elaborate in more details please?

Comment: When I scroll down the screen, I want the div(id=scrol) stop scrolling at a position but not always following.

Comment: Dear We are still not getting what exactly you want.. please clarify bit more..

Comment: I am not confirm that my answer is correct because i think what i have done is not the correct way in your situation but for demo purpose this is correct. Please suggest your views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?
I used the javascript **jQuery library**. If you don't know how to use jQuery leave a reply.
(For a better effect scroll by clicking the scroll and moving your mouse)

```js
const $scroll = $('#scrol');

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
  const st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if( st >= 240){
    $scroll.css({position: "absolute", top: 330});  
  }else{
    $scroll.css({position: "fixed", top: 100});  
  }       
});
```

Comment: @Happy I think that was the question.

Comment: Actually the question is bit confusing, so i think Sophia can tell more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below fiddle might be you want this if iam getting your problem correct but not fully sure..

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JjuQu/35/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JjuQu/35/embedded/result/